# Yii2 Console 'Class user does not exist'

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to run `./yii` from my base directory.  I used the console application a few months ago and it worked then.  I'm not sure what changed.

I get the following error:

```
Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class user does not exist'

in /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:415

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(415): ReflectionClass->__construct('user')
#1 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(358): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('user')
#2 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(151): yii\di\Container->build('user', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php(154): yii\di\Container->get('user')
#4 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php(128): yii\di\Instance->get(NULL)
#5 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php(98): yii\di\Instance::ensure('user', 'yii\web\User')
#6 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(107): yii\filters\AccessControl->init()
#7 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#8 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(372): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#9 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(151): yii\di\Container->build('yii\filters\Acc...', Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('yii\filters\Acc...', Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(180): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#12 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(518): yii\base\Component->__set('as beforeReques...', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(105): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\console\Application), Array)
#14 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(206): yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(85): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#16 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/yii(30): yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
#17 {main}
```

How do I fix this?

---

---

**UPDATE**

After adding the parameters to my `console\config\main.php` file as suggested, I am now getting the following error:

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownMethodException' with message 'Calling unknown method: yii\console\Request::getUserIP()'

in /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:285

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessRule.php(105): yii\base\Component->__call('getUserIP', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessRule.php(105): yii\console\Request->getUserIP()
#2 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php(118): yii\filters\AccessRule->allows(Object(yii\base\InlineAction), Object(yii\web\User), Object(yii\console\Request))
#3 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ActionFilter.php(71): yii\filters\AccessControl->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#4 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#5 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(541): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#6 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(607): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#7 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(139): yii\base\Module->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#8 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(91): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#9 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(455): yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#10 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(167): yii\base\Module->runAction('', Array)
#11 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(143): yii\console\Application->runAction('', Array)
#12 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#13 /var/www/html/beta/fs2/yii(31): yii\base\Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

Here is my main config file:

```
$params = array_merge(
//    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
//    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log', 'gii'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'modules' => [
        'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ],
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\UserConsole',
            //'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

The directory `console\controllers` is empty.

Comment: Show error row content

Comment: If you are not sure what has changed since then, it would probably be a good idea to add your project to source control, like Git or Mercurial :)

Comment: @jacmoe Thanks, but I work on an island in the Pacific with terrible internet so I tend to avoid services that require a connection.

Comment: @readtheBook Mercurial and Git are distributed version control - that means that you can use them without a connection :) ((They are serverless, in other words))

Answer (score 2):

Console application does not have `user` component. So, you need to configure `user` component in `/console/config/main.php`.

like as,

**/console/config/main.php**

```
 'components' => [
 .........
 ......
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            //'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
 .......
]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm now getting the error `Exception 'yii\base\UnknownMethodException' with message 'Calling unknown method: yii\console\Request::getUserIP()'`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is quite simple because user is a component. [Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-application-components.html#core-application-components) says about application components. So in Console application **'user'** does not exist. So, you need to configure user component in `config/main.php.` Then Try this code below:

```
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        'class' => 'WebUser',
    ),
    'session' => [ // for use session in console application
        'class' => 'yii\web\Session'
    ],
```

or

```
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
    ),
    'session' => [ // for use session in console application
        'class' => 'yii\web\Session'
    ],
```

user: represents the user authentication information. This component is only available in Web applications Please refer to the Authentication section for more details.